# Primes, Riemann-zeta and zeros not on the critical line, consequences?

Tags: roots, riemann-zeta

Which would be consequences on the distribution of primes if infinite number of Riemann-zeta zeros are in the critical strip but not on the critical line?

Comment: See this page: [Reddit: What Theorems will be true if the Riemann Hypothesis is proven false?](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/enb5q1/what_theorems_will_be_true_if_the_riemann/).

Comment: [One example](https://aimath.org/WWN/rh/articles/html/28a/) from the linked page is that RH is equivalent to a statement involving the error term of the PNT: that for all $\varepsilon$, $\pi (n) \in \operatorname{Li}(n)+\mathcal{O}(n^{1/2+\varepsilon})$. If your premise were true, this would be false.

Answer (score 0):

What you can say on $\pi(x)$ depends mainly on $\sigma_0=\sup \Re(\rho)$, and if the limit is not attained then how fast does $\Re(\rho)$ converge to $\sigma_0$, if the limit is attained is it by infinitely many zeros. The main thing to know is that it is very possible that $\sigma_0=1$ and that the strongest form of the PNT is (close to) the best possible error term for $\pi(x)-Li(x)$.